# How to determine which query line has no match in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am querying a mongo database in node.js, the query has two greater than conditions. If the query returns an empty result I would like to be able to tell which condition was not met, so I can tailor a message around that for the user. Using the code below as an example, in the callback function how can I tell if the result is empty because the weight condition wasn't met, or because the height condition wasn't met?

```js
  User.find({
                weight: {$gt: 180},
                height: { $gt: 6},
            }, function(err, res) {
                if (res.length == 0){
                    // Is there a way to tell which query
                    // weight: { $gt: 180 } or height: { $gt: 6} found no 
                    // match?
                    // I am trying to be more precise in the message I show 
                    // the user 
                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do so, maybe you can try use explain method which tells you much more information about your query.

Comment: To be clear, there is only **one query** here. Those are not actually separate conditions since the query in the question here is an *implicit AND* expression, which could otherwise be written as `{ "$and": [{ "weight": { "$gt": 180 }}, { "height": { "$gt": 12 } }] }`, but of course *looks nicer* as it is written without the `$and`. If you wanted to determine where **either** of those conditions matched documents and which documents where a match for **either**, then that would be an `$or` query instead. Just as pointed out in the linked answer.